# How To Use Here Maps Telematics Toll Cost With GPS Coordinates

Tags: gps, here-api

I am trying to calculate toll costs using HERE API https://tce.api.here.com/2/tollcost.json but I don't want to use link id's.  I only want to use GPS coordinates to map the path and find all of the toll costs that would be associated.  So far it looks like I need to use link id's?  If this is not the case can someone provide an example of the route value that is needed?

Answer (score 1):

Using our Fleet Telematics API, you can get the total toll cost between/along a set of GPS coordinates (waypoints).

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/calculation-considerations.html

This example (insert your  and ) will return the total toll cost along the whole route:

```
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&currency=EUR&rollups=total&waypoint0=52.51,13.42&waypoint1=45.747353,11.733903&tollVehicleType=3&app_id=<app_id>&app_code=<app_code>&routeMatch=1
```

You can also get details of the toll cost per country or per link ID if necessary using the `rollups` parameter.

Comment: So would I add all of the GPS coordinates for the route then?

Comment: That is if you are using the fleet telematics API (which supersedes the Toll Cost Extension API - TCE you are using) . However I see you are using the TCE, in that case you can use the route parameter with only link IDs.